# apt error "could not get lock..."

Tags: apt

[image]

I know that the sudo password is my account password. Buy when I type it that error messafe comes "Could not get lock.....". What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem! No worries! Try again later :)

You are running an upgrade at the same time. It is not possible to install new software until this upgrade is finished.